# Maximize window in Ubuntu 14.04 goes to wrong screen

Tags: 14.04

When I open e.g. a terminal when my pointer is on the left screen, it opens up in the right. I installed compiz as suggested, enabled "Place windows" and played with the settings. It doesn't seem to affect anything. Do I need to restart compiz or something after I change the setting?